# Firefox - Accessing add-on objects in web page script

Tags: firefox-addon

referring to recent Info provided by firefox that it is possible to access extension object in content safely. https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2012/08/20/exposing-objects-to-content-safely/

I am trying to do this in the hello world extension downloaded from Firefox website.

```
var sharedObject = { foo : "Hello!" };
window.wrappedJSObject.sharedObject = sharedObject;
```

and in my webpage JS I have

```
alert(window.sharedObject.foo);
```

But it says window.sharedObject undefined. Any clues ? I want to do it safely too but first I intend to get it working. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's the **contentWindow** you want to inject your object

```js
var sharedObject = { foo : "Hello!" };
contentWindow.wrappedJSObject.sharedObject = sharedObject;
```

Keep in mind that without the `__exposedProps__` property, `foo` will be `undefined` for the webpage code.